# Unable to ssh into a machine unless on the same network

Tags: 16.04, ssh, remote-desktop

I am trying to ssh from my home laptop(Ubuntu 16.04), which is on a private network, with IP 10.12.X.X, into my work machine, at a University network, with IP like 10.100.X.Y, which is running Ubuntu 16.04.

I am unable to establish the connection and get a "Connection timed out" message. But if I try to ssh when my laptop is on the same network as the work computer,it works flawlessly.

Any thoughts as to why this happens?

Comment: Please edit your question. What sort of IP-addresses does your machines have in the different types of network you have them in? Could it be that they both use private addresses and therefore aren't connectable from the outside? The question would need a bit more information regarding your network setup for anybody to be able to answer it. You don't need to post the actual IP-addresses, just give hints about how they look like.

Comment: Unless you are on the internet directly, it is not dangerous to post the complete IP as well, but usually, the first 2 numbers(in IPv4) should work. For example, post 172.16.120.123 as 172.16.X.Y. Knowing the IP addresses would make it easy to diagnose whether the problem is in NAT and requires port forwarding or not.

Comment: The work machine is on a University network and has an IP like 10.100.X.Y., and the home machine is on a private network with an IP of 10.12.X.X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't connect to a private network from the outside.  The University would have to give you a public IP for the machine you want to connect to.  Then they would have to handle port forwarding from their end to send the desired traffic (ie specific ports) to that machine.

The same goes for if you want to connect to your home computer from the University.  Your home computer on a router.  You would have to connect to your public IP (most likely the IP of your router or the provide modem from your IP) then have the traffic forwarded to the private IP of your computer.

The options you would look for in your modem's setup is `port forwarding` which would most likely be in the firewall or security section.

Companies that allow outside networking and connecting to their computers provide VPN (Virtual Private Network) connectivity where they provide their remove facilities the IP of a VPN so that they can be connected on the same network from different location.

There are other variations and schemes that can be used but that is the basic gist.

By the way, you can get your public 'IP Address' in a number of ways including clicking on a link such as [What is My Public IP Address](http://www.whatismypublicip.com/).